# Can we create Contact form using HTML and send mails without Server side programs?

Tags: html, email

I want to create application for sending emails only by using HTML.. ? Is it possible

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Read+Me&body=Happy+Candy+Day">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a [`mailto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) link:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again&body=How%20are%20you">
```